# order files by part of name

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that contains files=>filenames like so:

```
$provider1 = ('dnnbzdas04.txt','haethae09.txt','dhsdshnsd05.txt',...,'zdbtebt03.txt');
```

Similar to a rightmove file the text files have a 'sequence' value at the end,

the files do have unknown filenames BUT the 'sequence' is ALWAYS set, I need to reorder the array so that the result is:

```
$provider1Ordered = ('hst45ga01.txt','dfa454ba02.txt','zdbtebt03.txt',...,'haethae09.txt');
```

What I was looking to do is to use a sub_str() to strip away all but the last 6 characters and use this to order the array.

What would be the best way to marry up the new 6 character ordered array to the previous 'rawdata' array and order it in the same fashion?

- oh yes, the random characters also contain integers, there is no fixed file name length and the only thing I have that is definite is the sequence number at the end.

Please any pointer, help or anything I would be very grateful.

All the best,

Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with `usort`. For example

```
$provider1 = array('dnnbzdas04.txt','haethae09.txt','dhsdshnsd05.txt','zdbtebt03.txt');

usort($provider1, function($a, $b) {
    $a = substr($a, -6, 2);
    $b = substr($b, -6, 2);
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
});

print_r($provider1);
```

This would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => zdbtebt03.txt
    [1] => dnnbzdas04.txt
    [2] => dhsdshnsd05.txt
    [3] => haethae09.txt
)
```

Comment: This really did help me out, I was a bit lazy though and created a new array and when looping through the array of files, I used the sequence stripped out as the array index, this gave me the files in the right order, but your code put me on the path

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is based on your initial idea :

use a known [sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) , but instead of comparing the whole values of your array cells, indeed compare the "stripped" version of it. The the "switching" part can be done on the whole cell as usual. For the comparison, I would even focus on solely the sequence number, excluding the extension. Be carefull though that this implies your sequence won't go over 99...

Comment: Thanks, that really helped (sorry about the delay in replying)